# hci_get_route return "no such device"

Tags: bluetooth, yocto

I'm running on YOCTO and I've done a simple sw with only hci_get_route() so to understand how it work.
Before run the application I've activate the bluetooth:

```
systemctl enable bluetooth.service
systemctl start bluetooth.service
```

and check the status with

```
systemctl status bluetooth.service
```

and the response is "running", so I run the application but

```
hci_get_route
```

return a bad id and errno is "no such device". I'm forgetting something?

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked that the Bluetooth hardware is running and that the appropriate driver is loaded? All you have done so far is check that the Bluetooth stack is running, but that is not enough.

Comment: Hi, yes...I found the problem.................need to call brcm_patchram_plus to load the bt controller and after bring up the bt interface

Comment: Please if you found the solution, post your own solution and mark it as Correct, so future developers can find it.

Answer (score 0):

below the commands to activate the BT interface via command line :

1. `brcm_patchram_plus --patchram /etc/firmware/BCM43430A1.1DX.hcd --enable_hci --no2bytes --tosleep 50000 --baudrate 1000000 --use_baudrate_for_download /dev/ttyUSB0 & hciconfig -a`
2. `hciattach /dev/ttyUSB0 any`
3. `hciconfig hci0 up`

after this 3 steps `hcitool dev` show the bt interface and the call at `hci_get_route` works. The step 1 is not necessary after hw reboot, you need only to execute step 2 & 3

Comment: You should add that this solution is specifically for Broadcom hardware, and you should also specify the chipset. Other commands apply to hardware from other manufacturers.